# Change lunguage in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

Hellow everybody! I'm working on data visualizating on web site using flask as server for dash where all my graphs in table, I have 3 types of graphs: Pie, Scatter and Box, all from go. For Pie and Scatter I set all data using texts and hoxers, but I had problems with Box, becouse it have extra text: q1,q1,min,max,mediane which I can't edit. !Translated comments, added details

```
from dash import Dash, html, dash_table, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Russian_Russia')


def levelpie(df):#relationship amount for vacancies of different levels
    df1 = df.groupby('level')['level'].count().rename('Counts').reset_index()
    df1 = df1[df1['level'] != missing]
    labels = df1['level']
    values = df1['Counts']
    fig = go.Figure(data = go.Pie(labels = labels, values = values, hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='label+percent', textfont_size=15))
    fig.update_layout(width=300, height = 300)
    return fig


def dateline(df):#amount vacancies for each day
    df1 = df.groupby('published_at')['published_at'].count().rename('Counts').reset_index()
    df1 = df1[df1['published_at'] != missing]
    labels = df1['published_at']
    values = df1['Counts']
    fig = go.Figure(data = go.Scatter(x=labels, y=values, mode="lines+text"))
    fig.update_layout(width=500, height = 300)
    return fig


def salbox(df):#salary for different levels, graph which I want to translate
    df1 = df[df['level'] != missing]
    fig = []
    for i in df1['level'].unique():
        df2 = df1.loc[df1['level'] == i]
        df2['salary'] = (df2['min_salary'] + df2['max_salary']) / 2
        fig += [go.Box(y = df2['level'], x = df2['salary'],
                             orientation='h', name=i)]
    #fig.update_layout(width=500, height = 300)
    return fig


df_keys = pd.read_csv("files/key_words.csv", encoding = 'utf8', delimiter = ';')#данные для запросов для таблицы
table = [] #хранитель строк таблицы
target = df_keys.loc[:, :]
missing = 0 #replace for missing values
for i, row in target.iterrows():
    df = pd.read_csv("files/pythonfullvac.csv", encoding = 'utf8', delimiter = ';').fillna(missing) #information for response with filled missing
    avg_sal = int(((df['min_salary'] + df['min_salary'])/2).mean())
    table += [html.Tr([
            html.Th(["Профессия"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
            html.Th(["ИТ"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
            html.Th([row['name']], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
            html.Th([row['key']], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
            html.Th([len(df)], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
            
            html.Th([dcc.Graph(
            id='dateline' + str(i),
            figure=dateline(df)
            )], scope="col", style={"width":"100%;"}),
            
            html.Th([dcc.Graph(
            id='levelpie'+ str(i),
            figure=levelpie(df)
            )], scope="col", style={"width":"100%;"}),
            
            html.Th([avg_sal], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
            
            html.Th([dcc.Graph(
            id='salbox'+ str(i),
            figure={'data' : salbox(df),
                    'layout' : {
                        'width' : 500,
                        'height' : 300,
                        'locale': 'ru_EU}} )],#here was a try to change language of graph using framework locale, despite the attributes width and high worked locale not
                    
            scope="col", style={"width":"100%;"}),
        ])
    ]


from . import dash


dash.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Table([
                html.Thead([#names of columns of table 
                    html.Tr([
                        html.Th(["Тип"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Сфера"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Специализация"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Ключевые слова"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Кол.вакансий"], scope="col",style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Даты"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Соотношение уровней"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Ср.зарплата"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"}),
                        html.Th(["Зарплата по уровням"], scope="col", style={"width":"11%;"})
                    ])
                    ],
                    className = "thead-dark"),
                html.Tbody(#table's rows
                    table
                    )
                ], style = {"margin-bottom": 0, "margin-left": 0, "margin-right": "0%", "margin-top": 0}),
          ], width=12)  
    ])

], fluid=True)
```

So  I tried to switch locale and set parameter 'locale':'ru_Ru' in layout of dcc.Graph with Box, but it doesn't work properly(lunguage still english), it was only way for me right now, and i'm asking for your help. Here [screen of box graph when I runned the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6LnM.png) I want all red text(min, q1, lower fence, median, q3, upper fence, max) was translated to Russian in this graph. Do you know how to change language in plotly, dash or way to change this text or delete this text and put mine?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If we take your image as starting point, what do you want to see changed?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I will try to give you more details. Most of text in plotly we can change to Russian, because we have special attributes like hovertext, text, name etc. but we have problems with box graph, as you can see on pinned screen, it has text which appears when mouse on it, like q1, min, max, q3, median. The point is that we don't set this text by attributes, it's automatically sets, and I need to change this text to Russian version for example instead "median" (in the middle of the box) put "среднее значение" thus way with rest of them, because this site for Russian people.